# Understanding DBL_MAX

Tags: c, floating-point, double, double-precision

I just read about the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard in order to understand how [single-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [double-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating points are implemented.

So I wrote this to check my understanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    double foo = 9007199254740992; // 2^53
    double bar = 9007199254740993; // 2^53 + 1

    printf("%d\n\n", sizeof(double)); // Outputs 8. Good
    printf("%f\n\n", foo); // 9007199254740992.000000. Ok
    printf("%f\n", bar); // 9007199254740992.000000. Ok because Mantissa is 52 bits
    printf("%f\n\n", DBL_MAX); // ??

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
8

9007199254740992.000000

9007199254740992.000000

179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
```

What I don't understand is that I expected the last line of my output to be: (2^53-1) * 2^(1024-52), but the number on the last line corresponds approximately to 2^(2^10). What am I missing? How `DBL_MAX` is calculated exactly?

**EDIT:** Little explanation about the **exact value** of `DBL_MAX`:

As explained in the accepted answer the largest value of the exponent is 2^1023 and not 2^1024 as I tought. So the **exact** value of `DBL_MAX` is:
**`(2^53-1)*(2^(1023-52))`** (so as expected it's slightly smaller than 2^10 since the mantissa is a bit smaller than 2)

Comment: `%d` requires an argument of type `int`. `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t`. Use `%zu` to print it: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(double));`. Using `%d` can happen to work, depending on your system's characteristics, but it's not reliable.

Comment: Yes you're right. That was just for the test :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double are represented as `m*2^e` where `m` is the mantissa and `e` is the exponent. Doubles have 11 bits for the exponent. Since the exponent can be negative there is an offset of `1023`. That means that the real calculation is `m*2^(e-1023)`. The largest 11 bit number is `2047`. The exponent `2047` is reserved for storing `inf` and `NaN`. This means the largest double is `m*2^(2046-1023) = m*2^(1023)`. The mantissa is a number between 1 and 2. This means that the largest double is attained when `m` is almost 2. So we have:

```
DBL_MAX = max(m)*2^1023 ~ 2*2^1023 = 2^1024 = 2^(2^10)
```

As you can see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E1024) this is pretty much the standard value of `DBL_MAX`.

Comment: Yeah sorry must have deleted it by mistake.

Comment: Totally correct, but the exponent bias is 1023, and the maximum exponent is reserved for infinity and nan, hence DBL_MAX has an exponent of 2046 - 1023 = 1023.

Answer (score 2):

`DBL_MAX` is the largest *value* a double can hold.  Its value is not related to the number of bits in the mantissa.

The limit is mostly related to the maximum exponent.  For IEEE-754, it is about 1.8e+308 or 2^1023.

The definition is usually `#define DBL_MAX      1.79769313486231470e+308`